# OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (13)")

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, mysql-python

I have the following error on App Engine at the first connection of my flask projects:
OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (13)")

The connection is done by the following code:
db = MySQLdb.connect(CLOUDSQL_HOST, CLOUDSQL_USER, CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD, db_instance)

I don't understand why my code on my local machine, with dev_appserver.py, works fine but on the cloud doesn't work.

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use App Engine native UNIX sockets to connect to your Cloud SQL instance when running on App Engine. So, you can use something like in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#code_sample_overview):

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
        cloudsql_unix_socket = os.path.join(
            '/cloudsql', CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME)

        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            unix_socket=cloudsql_unix_socket,
            user=CLOUDSQL_USER,
            passwd=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD)
else:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=CLOUDSQL_USER, passwd=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD)
```

You can get your `CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME` field from either the console or with the command `gcloud sql instances describe YOUR_INSTANCE`. It will be something like:
`connectionName: YOUR-PROJECT:REGION-OF-THE-INSTANCE-INSTANCE-NAME`